# Geometrical representation of $|z-i|<2|z-2|$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

$$|z-i|<2|z-2|$$
Where $$i=\sqrt{-1}$$ and z is a complex number.

Now my question how to know what this is representing geometrically in $Argand$ plane or just simply what region or curve this is representing. I have solved it.
My method: Put $z=x+iy$ then
$$\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}<2\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}$$
$$x^2+y^2+1-2y<4x^2+16-16x+4y^2$$
$$3x^2+3y^2-16x+2y+15>0$$
So after putting $(0,0)$ which lies outside the circle.

But I wanted to know if there was any other way to know its geometry not something completely relying on some arithmetic calculations. Any geometrical approach or related to something that. I am in high school(senior).

Comment: I think it should be exterior of a circle.

Comment: I have tried with this method and I can solve it but I wanted another method(if possible) to know its geometry.

Comment: @Gaurav Mishra:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mkisgrzip8                                      check the slider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, if you are looking for a geometrical approach, consider the frontier of this domain as being a [**circle of Apollonius**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius) which is the set of points $M$ such that

$$MA=k MB \ \text{with} \ k=2, \ A:=(0,1), \ B:=(2,0)$$

(a kind of generalized line bissector, a case covered by value $k=1$).

Relationship

$$MA < 2 MB$$

gives the **interior** of this circle.

Here is how one can determine the center and radius of such circles :

Consider line $AB$ :

1. It is clearly an axis of symmetry of the frontier circle.
2. Consider the 2 points $M_1$ and $M_2$ of this line $[AB]$ defined resp. in the following way:

$$\begin{cases}\vec{M_1A}&=&-2 \vec{M_1B} &\implies M_1A=2M_1B\\ \ \ \ \vec{M_2A}&=&2 \vec{M_2B}&\implies M_2A=2M_2B\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

(1) can be written in a barycentrical way like this:

$$\begin{cases}M_1&=&\tfrac13 A + \tfrac23 B&=&\binom{4/3}{1/3}\\  M_2&=&2B-A&=&\binom{4}{-1}\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

As a consequence $\{M_1,M_2\}$ constitute the intersection of the frontier circle with line $AB$.

With words, $M_1$ is inside line segment $[AB]$, at the two thirds of it (closer to $B$). The other one, $M_2$, is exterior to line segment $[AB]$, closer to $B$, precisely symmetrical of $A$ with respect to $B$.

Therefore, as the frontier circle is symmetrical with respect to line $AB$, $M_1M_2$ is a diameter of this circle, giving immediately access to its center $\tfrac12(M_1+M_2)=\binom{\ \ \ 8/3}{-1/3}$ and its radius.

Comment: Shouldn't it be exterior of the circle?

Comment: Yeah I will see the procedure. Thanks

Comment: I don't think i totally understand the Wikipedia page it's my fault. Can you explain me a little bit about what you said getting directly center and radius of such circles. If possible. Thank you.

Comment: OK. I add information to my answer.

Comment: Thank you that will be really appreciable.

Comment: Edit to the answer just done.